# How to make custom function that returns all applicable rows in PHP

Tags: php, function, select, mysqli, row

Below is my custom function that will take care the queries I call:

```
<?php
function cusQuery($sql){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "366y~V3g4n";
    $dbname = "learnTurkishDesktop";


     $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $output = array();

    if($result->num_rows>0){
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                //as you see I tried to output all rows using print_r and it worked but I want it to just return an array containing all applicable rows and the call should handle the rest(formatting and which columns to include).
                print_r($output[] = $row);
            }

    }else{
        return array("0 results");
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Now I am calling the my cusQuery function at my index.php

```
<?php
        include('myFunctions.php');

        $myQuery = cusQuery("SELECT Title, Content FROM user_created_notebooks");

            echo "<h4>". $myQuery['Title']." ".$myQuery['Content']."</h4>";

?>
```

I tried using for loop in my function call but it didn't work. Below is the reference of what I'm trying to do:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/126144-shortest-way-to-write-a-mysql-fetch-query/

I also tried not using while loop in the function itself just like the example given in the link but it only outputs the first applicable row.

I would love to hear new ideas too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, this function is wrong in many ways. For starter, it shouldn't connect to a database server every time it is called. Instead, An existing connection should be reused. Besides, any custom query function that doesn't have support for **prepared statements** can be considered **harmful**.

Comment: Thanks @YourCommonSense , could you please elaborate more the "An existing connection should be reused". I'm thinking that I should connect to server in the beginning of my index.php then closed it and the function will just open it for me.

Comment: Yes, exactly. this is how it should be. However with your current function a new connection will be made every time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

The reference given works perfectly because only one row was returned from the database.  "SELECT name FROM table WHERE ID = '$var'";

For your case  the "$output[] = $row" statement  creates a multidimentional  array
of associative arrays contained with in a numeric array  so the method does not work. below is how you should loop over the results

```
if(!empty($output)){
    foreach($output as $row){
        echo "h4 {$row['Title']} {$row['content']}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this before but I  want to return the whole array when the function is called, I mean the echo thing should be in my index.php just like in the reference so I can re-use that function for tables with different column names.